# How to use $arrayElemAt with MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I have the following pipeline, which I want to use it in Golang and convert it to bson.M. One way is using bson.UnmarshalExtJSON but I want to know what is exact equivalent of bson.M of this pipeline. In fact my problem is in $arrayElemAt line.

```
            "$lookup": {
                        "from" : "cities",
                        "localField": "cityId",
                        "foreignField": "_id",
                        "as" : "city"
                    }}
            , {
            "$project": {
              "_id": 0,
              "name": 1,
              "age": 1,
              "city": { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$city.name", 0]}
            }}
```

I use this bson.M:

```
   stage1 := bson.M{
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from": "cities",
            "localField": "cityId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as" : "city",
        },
    }

    stage2 := bson.M{
        "$project": bson.M{
            "_id": 0,
            "name": 1,
            "age": 1,
            "city": bson.M{ "$arrayElemAt" : bson.M{"$city.name", 0} },
        },
    }

    pipeline := make([]bson.M, 0)

    pipeline = append(pipeline, stage1)
    pipeline = append(pipeline, stage2)
```

The above code gives me compiler error: *missing key in map literal* at the line I have *"city": bson.M{ "$arrayElemAt" : bson.M{"$city.name", 0} }*. So what is the correct way of defining $arrayElemAt as bson.M?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to translate

```
"city": { "$arrayElemAt" : ["$city.name", 0]}
```

would be:

```
bson.M{"$arrayElemAt":[]interface{}{"$city.name",0}
```

You were getting the compile error because of this:

```
bson.M{"$city.name", 0}
```

`bson.M` is a map, thus the correct syntax should use a `:` instead of a `,`.

Comment: I had to remove $ in city.name, because I received runtime error for that, and with out $ I recieved another error about  "FieldPath field names may not contain '.'." , and when I remove city. I received again another error: Expression $arrayElemAt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.

Comment: Looking at the original pipeline, I see `"$arrayElemAt" : ["$city.name", 0]`. That's an array, so the correct way is: `bson.M{"$arrayElemAt":[]interface{}{"$city.name",0}}`

Comment: yes, that was the trick, do you want to edit your answer so I mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use below syntax work for you where bson.A for array:

bson.M{ "$arrayElemAt": bson.A{"$city.name", 0}}

Comment: best answer shinpai !